# Random.value to bool?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This [Minesweeper Tutorial](http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-minesweeper-game) uses Random.value to convert to bool:

```
mine = Random.value < 0.15;
```

Can anyone explain how this works? As far as I understand is that Random.value returns a float. How does it convert to bool there and why is it followed by > 0.15?

Answer (score 10):

The condition `Random.value < 0.15` returns a boolean value, it returns `true` if `Random.value` is less than `0.15`, false otherwise. Then that value is assigned to `mine`.

More generally, `Random.value < 0.15` is a [*boolean expression*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_expression) that uses [`less than < Operator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5wecxwa.aspx).And each boolean expression evalutes to either `true` or `false`.